# Using PHPUnit code coverage with interfaces

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm using PHPUnit (3.6.7) to test and provide code coverage reports on my application, everything is set-up and working as expected.

I have complete coverage for all of the code except for my interfaces, even though I have tests that for classes that implement the interfaces. The report just states that the interface was not executed

Is there a way to cover the interfaces? Or is it a case of telling PHPUnit to ignore them for code coverage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify that tests for a concrete class cover methods from parent abstract classes/interfaces.

See `Specifying Covered Methods` section in [Code Coverage Analysis](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) chapter in the manual.

In the same chapter you'll also find ways to ignore blocks of code or entire files from code coverage analysis.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. For anyone else that come across this, you need @covers Class_Name<extended> in you test class doc block

Comment: Updated link to latest version's manual page: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html

Answer (score 5):

Just as an additional answer:

The next release of PHPUnit (`3.7.`) will ignore all interfaces for coverage by default.

So it will not necessary to use any sort of includes or `//@codeCoverageIgnore` ways to work around then.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces contain no executable code, so there's nothing there to test.

Comment: I'm not trying to test them directly, though they do get used with  assertInstanceOf(), I just want them in the code coverage as they are being "used"